# Updated Value is not showing in dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to JavaScript. We are creating dropdown dynamically and populating its value. On the first run, options are showing correct values. But if I click other links, coming back to the same page again, it should display new values because we are populating it with new option values, but it is displaying the first/old values.

First time screen:

[image: First time Screen]

Second visit screen:

[image: Second Visit Screen]

JS code:

```
var that = this;
var fliest = "";
$("#report").hide();
$("#Stratify").html("");
$.each(this.Nodes, function (index, node){
    if (node.IsVariable() && node.NodeID() !== that.Node.NodeID()) {
        fliest += "<option value='" + node.NodeID() + "'>" + node.NodeName().trim() + "</option>";
    }
});
$("#Stratify").empty().append(fliest);

if ($("#Stratify")[0].length < 1) {
    //alert("You must have 2 or more variable defined in your project for this report.");
    $("#notificationContent").html("You must have 2 or more variable defined in your project for this report.");
    $("#commonNotification").show();
    return false;
}
$("#StratifyBy legend").text("Select the variable you wish to use to stratify " + this.Node.NodeName());

$("#commonModalHeader").empty().text("Frequency distribution with stratification");
$("#commonModalBodyContent").empty().append($("#StratifyBy").clone());
$('#commonModalCloseBtn').unbind('click');
$("#commonModalCloseBtn").text("Cancel");
$('#commonModalActionBtn').unbind('click');
$("#commonModalActionBtn").text("Generate").click(function () { that.IssueRequest($("#Stratify").val(), this); });
$("#commonModal").show();
```

What do I need to do in order to get the fresh value in second visit?

Comment: Are you attempting to *store* the value somewhere?   localstorage / session / a server-side database?

Comment: No we are not storing. Can you suggest code how can we store drop-down value except  session or database because we are not using both.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API

Answer (score 0):

Every time you load a page in a web browser it's as if it's the first time.  Unless you save data somewhere it will never know your intent.  You either need to store them server-side in a database (which is probably overkill for your needs) or locally in the browser using something like [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Here's a simple example

```js
//Get the saved items. If they don't exist yet (never been saved) then return an empty array.
//Note that you need to use JSON.parse because items are saved as strings and we need to parse that string into a real object/array/whatever
const list = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('my_items')) || [];

console.log('Saved Values:', list)

function addNewItem(val) {
  //Push the value into the local array
  list.push(val);
  
  //Save the newly updated array to localstorage for future use
  //Note that we must convert this array into a string representation of the array
  localStorage.setItem('my_items', JSON.stringify(list));
  
  console.log('New Value Added:', val);
  console.log('All Values:', list)
}
```

So with that example, your application can just call `addNewItem('apples')` and it will be added to the local `list` array, but also save it to the browser `localStorage` every time it is changed.  This means you can refresh the page and the `list` array should be the same as it was before the refresh.

Comment: Using local storage for such kind of parameters sounds a bit weird. That will tie the result to a specific browser on a specific machine. These things are usually handled server-side, aren't they?

Comment: Yes, but it depends on your needs and requirements. If the question asker is struggling to understand how basic web standards work, asking them to also set up a server and a database may be a bit beyond their abilities right now. A few lines of JS added can make their app work quickly if their needs are not beyond this. It just depends. This is an option

Comment: Implemented code but getting below exception.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: list is not defined at list.push(values);

Comment: Stratification.prototype.addNewItem = function (values) {
      list.push(values);  //Here giving ERRO "list is not defined
      localStorage.setItem('Stratify', JSON.stringify(values));
}

Comment: Calling from application here.                                                                                         Stratification.prototype.Activate = function () {
    $.each(this.Nodes, function (index, node) {
        if (node.IsVariable() && node.NodeID() !== that.Node.NodeID()) {
            fliest += "<option value='" + node.NodeID() + "'>" + node.NodeName().trim() + "</option>";
        }
    });

    const list = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Stratify')) || [];
    if(fliest.length !== 0){
    this.addNewItem(fliest);
    }

Comment: Well... the code above defines the `list` variable and it works fine as-is.  This is just example code.  `list` is an array of strings that can be added to. You have to change this code to work in whatever you are working with. I am assuming you know how to work with an array.   FYI: Posting a bunch of code like that in the comments on an answer is very difficult to read and understand. You may want to start a new question that is more specific on how to get your code to work without errors as these comments are not a good way to debug code

Comment: It was my mistake. I declared const list = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Stratify')) || []; inside function. I make this declarition global ouside function. Error is not coming

Comment: I am pushing below value in list and getting below error.                                                     fliest += "<option value='" + node.NodeID() + "'>" + node.NodeName().trim() + "</option>";                                                                                                                             Uncaught TypeError: list.push is not a function

Comment: @PrabhashMishra Please make a new question. These comments are not a great place to debug your code. Generally though this means that `list` is not an array if the `push` method is not being found. You have not declared it properly. Please make a new question that shows your current code.